# How do I receive data on the server side of an SSL connection?

Tags: ssl, openssl, server, client

I'm trying to learn how to write a client/server application to transfer files to and from a server using SSL.  I've mostly figured out the client side using cURL and/or OpenSSL in C++, but I'm stumped on the server side...  I have experience using Perl and other cgi-bin type scripts but I haven't been able to find any tutorials on how to actually receive the data on the server side, only about the certificates and the authentication. Any help would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the `BIO_s_accept()` family of functions to accept connections over SSL (example code: https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/BIO_set_bind_mode.html).  You want `BIO_set_accept_bios()` to use the same wrappers for new connections and `BIO_set_bind_mode()` to keep listening for more connections on the same port.

You then call `connection = BIO_pop(accept);` to get a BIO representing each connection, which you can use for input and output.  `BIO_free()` when you’re done with it.

**Edit:** For practical, real-world use, use `scp` instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Do I have to have a program then constantly running on the server?  I have a web hosting account and I'm not sure how I would set that up.

Comment: Well, the server has to be running at the time you connect to it. `xinetd` can start a server process as needed.

Comment: Can I set up a script in the cgi-bin in say Perl to accept a connection and have my client call it

Comment: At this point, I should bring up that the way to transfer files over an encrypted connection to your webserver is in fact `scp`.  On a properly-configured server, the firewall will not permit you to open new ports.

Comment: okay, my server supports SSH, so SCP/SSH should be the easiest route?

Comment: Yes.  That’s the practical solution.